# Animate Over Shooting Mouse Click JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick, jquery-animate

I have the basic idea of my JavaScript operational.

The point of my JavaScript is to make an image of id 'player' move to the position that I click with the mouse, only when I click on the div with the id of 'stage' with the animation lasting 3 seconds.

At the same time, when the animation is running the head should change to 'player is moving' as opposed to when it is still and displaying 'player is still'.

Right now, in Chrome (maybe its a bug with  Chrome) the basic functionality of the JS works. However, it seems to overshoot the position of where I click the mouse on the first round and then barely move when I click again in the 'stage' div.

If anyone sees where I might be running into a problem please let me know!

Here's my EDITED JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#stage').click(function(e){
    $('#header h1').html('Player is moving!');
    $('#player').animate({
        top: e.pageY + 'px',
        left: e.pageX + 'px'
    }, 3000, function(){
        $('#header h1').html('Player is standing still...');
    });     
});
```

});

I have fixed my CSS issue, so don't worry about that but the code is located below for the CSS in case anyone thinks the issue may lie within.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's the CSS. The issue has been solved but it has been provided for convenience if you think the issue of the image overshooting the image may lie within for any reason:

```
#header {
width: 600px;
margin: 20px auto 10px;
padding: 5px;
background-color: whiteSmoke;
border: 1px solid #aaa;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
}
#header h1 {
text-align: center;
margin: 0;
}
#stage {
overflow: hidden;
width: 600px;
height: 400px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 5px;
background-color: whiteSmoke;
border: 1px solid #aaa;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
position: relative;
}
#player {
position: absolute;
width: 36px;
}
```

Comment: I believe e.clientX, e.clientY will be more appropriate to get current mouse position. Also, keep in mind how you want the image position relative to the mouse click. If you want to center it, you have to subtract half the width of the image, if you want it to be placed *before* the mouse click, subtract the entire width.

Comment: @andbeyond I do indeed want the current mouse click position to be passed to the animate function hence why I used the e.client. I'm confused by the rest of your answer.... please provide more detail?

Comment: ok, your code indicates you're using `e.pageX,e.pageY`, so you may want to update that. On the other point, if you just use clientX and clientY, the images top left point will go to that point. Therefore you might need to subtract or add a bit to the clientX,clientY values to position the images to your liking. Try it out and you'll see how it works.

Comment: @andbeyond I notice the difference now! I changed e.pageX and e.pageY as directed to clientX and clientY, then tried e.clientX, e.clientY and still the same result occurred. Either it did not move at all or it did not move to the mouse click exactly. Perhaps I'm not quite getting it. If you could provide a solid code example in the answer section I think that would help if you're up to it!

Comment: well, I stole the fiddle from the answer below but tweaked it to work, from here you can review the example and figure it out. Its probably something with your css. http://jsfiddle.net/WAHPA/1/

Comment: its actually this one http://jsfiddle.net/WAHPA/2/

Comment: the solution I found turned out to be using e.offsetY and e.offsetX. Apparently those others like client and page assume the image is beginning in the top left corner at 0,0, so when I'd click in the div it'd move the distance from the top corner to the click thus leading to the issues. offset corrects this issue. thanks for your response though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poor man's example : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WAHPA/) but it works in FF and Chrome.
Also, I'm curious what styles you lose, simple color style is always applied.

So more information is needed, can you share the complete css?

**Update**:  I'm still not seeing an issue in chrome (with the fiddle example)
Change #stage to something like

```
#stage {width:600px;height:600px;background-color:#333;position:fixed;top:20;left:0;}
```

Your player vs page is lying about it's position or where you can click.  I wanted the stage to be a fixed item on the page, non-moving.  I don't see any other reason (in your CSS or jQuery) why it'd overshoot.

​

Comment: thanks for your response. Your answer prompted me to investigate a bit further. As noted in my edited question, I tried a few other things and found if I included the h1 tag as well it was actually the automatic css included with the h1 tag that was going wrong. Now it works on this issue. If you know how to fix the issue of the overshooting image to the mouse I'd be extremely grateful as well!